# Load Next Post On Scroll - Like Infinite Scroll

Tags: jquery

I'm using the below script to load the next posts by clicking a button:

```
  jQuery('#showMore').click(function(event) {
       if (jQuery('#loader1').length) {
        jQuery('#loader1').hide();
       }
      jQuery('#showMore').text('Loading..');
      jQuery('#showMore').after('<img src="/wp-content/plugins/store/images/co/ajax-loader.gif" id="loader1">');
      if (jQuery('#no-more').length) {
       jQuery('#no-more').remove();
       }
         event.preventDefault();
         $number = jQuery('#product_grid li').length;

        jQuery.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/wp-content/plugins/store/ajax_more.php",
           data: "count=" + jQuery('#product_grid li').size(),
           success: function(results){
             jQuery('#product_grid').append(results);
             jQuery('#showMore').text('View More Products');
             jQuery('#loader1').hide();
           }
         });

  });
```

Now, I wanted the script to load the next posts on scroll instead of clicking a button..
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Unrelated, but note you do not have to test for `length` not being `0` before calling a method. It is safe to call methods on empty jQuery objects (it will just not do anything).

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery(window).scroll event for it.

**Example :**

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
   // existing stuff
});
```

You can control the load data callback according to scrollTop property. mean when current $.ajax request get called according to the amount of scroll.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).unbind(‘scroll’);  
if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {  
  //send request based on your cursor if more data available.  
}
```